# Do end users need to have packages/modules installed on their devices?

Tags: python

I'm building a program that uses beautiful soup and JSON. Once I've added a GUI and made this user-friendly, how would I go about having the end-user be able to use the program if they didn't have beautiful soup and JSON installed on their devices?

Is there some way to include the packages or modules in the program?

Comment: This question needs more focus. Given that a bazillion tutorials on how to package a Python program can be found via google, please explain the exact challenge you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) for that purpose.

> PyInstaller reads a Python script written by you. It analyzes your code to discover every other module and library your script needs in order to execute. Then it collects copies of all those files – including the active Python interpreter! – and puts them with your script in a single folder, or optionally in a single executable file.